# The most regex-y way to understand commutative operations?

Tags: python, regex

I want to parse both 1.05*f and f*1.05 to be equivalent things where f is a fixed letter, the number is any positive float and the * is always between the 'f' and the float (i.e. multiplication).  If there is no multiplication, then that is ok too and 'f' as the entire string is ok - so the '1.05*' is optional.  Note that 1.05*f*1.05 should not work. gf*1.05 should not work and f*1.05f should break.

I am using python.  I am actually having a hard time getting the f*1.05 to work by itself because f*1.05f also works - when I put a dollar sign at the end of the option multiplication and float then nothing works.

```
^f(\\*(\\d*[.])?\\d+)? # f*1.05 matches, but unfortunately so does f*1.05f
^f((\\*(\\d*[.])?\\d+)?)$ # the $ makes f*1.05f not match, but f*1.05 doesn't match either!
```

Really my question is about whether there is a clever way to make 1.05*f, f, and f*1.05 work all in one go without using a '|' operator to choose between the float being on the left or right.

Comment: Why would you not want to use a disjunction operator for a disjunction?

Comment: Are you trying to parse a more general expression syntax?  There are some excellent techniques for doing that.

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: does `^((f\*)?\d+[.]?\d+(\*f)?[^f]?)$` do what you need?

Comment: @JKirchartz - not quite because f*1.1*f should not work.  I also had to put a parentheses around \d+[.] because integers should work too.

Comment: @L3viathan - I guess I was interested in whether there was a way to say that if a string starts with X, it doesn't end with Y and if a string ends with Y, it doesn't start with X.

Comment: @DietrichEpp - yes a more general thing as I said to L3viathan, I was interested in whether there was a way to say that if a string starts with X, it doesn't end with Y and if a string ends with Y, it doesn't start with X.

Comment: @FinanceGuyThatCantCode Well, as you can see in my answer, it does work, but it's pretty ugly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Negative look(ahead|behind)s to the rescue:

```
pattern=r'((?!.*f\*)[\d.]+\*)?f((?<!\*f)\*[\d.]+)?'

s="""1.05*f*1.05
1.05*f
f*1.05
f"""

for line in s.split("\n"):
    if re.match(pattern, line):
        print("yay")
    else:
        print("nay")
```

prints:

```
nay
yay
yay
yay
```

**Explanation:** The pattern consists of two optional groups (the number groups) and an f in the middle. The left group has a negative lookahead in front of it, matching any sequence of characters, followed by an f and an asterisk. This lookahead will therefore not match if the f somewhere further down the string is followed by an asterisk. The whole group is optional (`?`). The `f` is then followed by the same thing again, but this time checking for a `*f` directly before it, using a negative lookbehind. If it finds that, the group won't match, which won't break the whole regex since it's again optional.

I still don't understand why you would want that, a `|` is vastly superior.

Comment: Yea...that is pretty ugly though I did learn about the negative look ahead/behind which is clearly a useful feature.  The | operator on my three options is certainly more readable/maintainable.  This does match my three cases of 'f', 'f*1.1', '1.1*f' - it does also match 'ff' and 'ff*1.1' which is bad - however I certainly got something out of your answer.  With some slight modification it could probably fix the matches that should not work, but I am satisfied.

Comment: You can also do the negative lookahead for `*f*` in the beginning, like `^(?!.*?\*f\*)([\d.]+\*)?f(\*[\d.]+)?$`

Comment: to be clear, I am using the | method - was a bit of a curiosity if the other way could be done easily. thx

Answer (score 1):

With multi-line modifier on:

```
^(?:f\*\d*\.\d+|\d*\.\d+\*f|f)$
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/uU8uM0/2)

Comment: Yes - I had a solution like that, but was curious about whether there was a way to say that if a string starts with X, it doesn't end with Y and if a string ends with Y, it doesn't start with X. Seems things get really ugly really fast with little benefit.